# Ruby map/collect is slow on a large Mongoid collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Mongoid collection on which I run a `where` query.

Now, I would like to build an array containing a values of a specific field from all the documents in the collection.

e.g. if my Monogid model is

```
class Foo
    field :color, type: String
end
```

I'd like to do something like this -

```
red_ducks = Foo.where(color: 'red')
red_duck_ids = red_ducks.map(&:_id)
```

Unfortunately, when the result of the query is large it takes a long time. It takes 6 seconds for 10,000 documents in my case, for example.

Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Do you really need 10k ids all at once?

Comment: Unfortunately yeah I do. I use it in a followup query like

`red_duck_owners = Bar.where(:foo_ids.in => red_duck_ids)`

Comment: I'd look at finding a better way to do it, pulling 10k ids out and then sending them back in is never going to be quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just call distinct on your scope with _id as an attribute?

```
red_duck_ids = Foo.where(color: 'red').distinct(:_id)
```

Which will return you a list of all `_id`s that meet your conditions. You can find more information on [Mongo's `distinct` documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/).

You can also have a look at [`only`](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#only) and if you are using version 3.1 or newer you can also use [`Criteria#pluck`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html).

Comment: @muistooshort as a matter of fact distinct is returning only the values of the field specified so it serves exactly your purpose: it will return you a list of all ids meeting your criteria, without first loading each entry as an object in memory. See http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html

Comment: Glad I could help! The reason it's so much faster is that it happens on a DBMS level. You ask Mongo to find the IDs and return you these. The `.map(&:_id)` is fetching all records and loads them in memory (as Ruby objects), asking each object for its `_id`.

Comment: @rkon: Thanks, I didn't know it was smart enough to send the distinct right down into MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
Foo.where(color: 'red').pluck(:id)
```

might be faster (not sure)

Comment: It is actually faster. `pluck` takes 0.3-0.5 seconds for 10k ids. Would be interested in an explantation on why it is 10x faster than `map`

Comment: I know that map evaluate every record in the collection so the map will run 10k+ queries... But i really don't know how pluck works, maybe it depends on something in mongodb to run a special query once